# characteristic polynomial of linear combination of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and $B$ is $f_A(x)$ and $f_B(x)$, is there any formula or result on the characteristic polynomial of $sA+tB$, say, $f_{sA+tB}(x)$, where $s,t$ are two numbers.

If this is complex, what if $A$ and $B$ are some special matrices, like symmetric, rank one, etc. Thanks!